# Improve performance of update where exists

Tags: sql, performance

The below query is running forever. Can someone please tell me how to improve its performance?

```
    Query:  update fsa_ip_mth_end_fin_aggregate tbl2
    set (team_acip_gss_sls_cry_am,team_sr_gss_sls_cry_am)  =         
         (select acip_gss_sls_cry_am , sr_gss_sls_cry_am
         from (select agg.current_fsa_ip_id current_fsa_ip_id, 
                       sum(base1.sr_gss_sls_cry_am) sr_gss_sls_cry_am, 
                       sum(base1.acip_gss_sls_cry_am) acip_gss_sls_cry_am  
                from ip_dim base,
                     ip_dim member,
                     ip_team_hierarchy_brdg,
                     fsa_ip_mth_end_fin_aggregate base1,
                     fsa_ip_mth_end_fin_aggregate agg 
                where ip_team_hierarchy_brdg.base_ip_dim_id = base.ip_dim_id 
                and ip_team_hierarchy_brdg.member_ip_dim_id = member.ip_dim_id 
                and ip_team_hierarchy_brdg.active_in = 'Y' 
                and base.dim_active_in = 'Y'
                and member.dim_active_in = 'Y' 
                and base1.current_fsa_ip_id = base.current_fsa_ip_id 
                and agg.current_fsa_ip_id = member.current_fsa_ip_id 
                and ip_team_hierarchy_brdg.allocation_factor != 0 
                and agg.current_fsa_ip_id = base1.current_fsa_ip_id
                group by agg.current_fsa_ip_id) tbl1
            where tbl1.current_fsa_ip_id = tbl2.current_fsa_ip_id)               
where exists                  
(select sr_gss_sls_cry_am,acip_gss_sls_cry_am 
         from (select agg.current_fsa_ip_id current_fsa_ip_id, 
                       sum(base1.sr_gss_sls_cry_am) sr_gss_sls_cry_am, 
                       sum(base1.acip_gss_sls_cry_am) acip_gss_sls_cry_am  
                from ip_dim base,
                     ip_dim member,
                     ip_team_hierarchy_brdg,
                     fsa_ip_mth_end_fin_aggregate base1,
                     fsa_ip_mth_end_fin_aggregate agg 
                where ip_team_hierarchy_brdg.base_ip_dim_id = base.ip_dim_id 
                and ip_team_hierarchy_brdg.member_ip_dim_id = member.ip_dim_id 
                and ip_team_hierarchy_brdg.active_in = 'Y' 
                and base.dim_active_in = 'Y'
                and member.dim_active_in = 'Y' 
                and base1.current_fsa_ip_id = base.current_fsa_ip_id 
                and agg.current_fsa_ip_id = member.current_fsa_ip_id 
                and ip_team_hierarchy_brdg.allocation_factor != 0 
                and agg.current_fsa_ip_id = base1.current_fsa_ip_id
                group by agg.current_fsa_ip_id) tbl1
            where tbl1.current_fsa_ip_id = tbl2.current_fsa_ip_id);
```

I tried the syntax:

```
    update (select query...) 
    set (team_acip_gss_sls_cry_am,team_sr_gss_sls_cry_am) = (select query...)
```

But this did not work because of group by/aggregate functions involved.

I also tried 'IN' instead of EXISTS. Both have almost the same performance. Please guide me in this regard.

Comment: Have you put indexes on all fields used in a `group by` or `where` clause?

Comment: You're trying to do too much in one query.  Use a stored proc, and break your problem down.

Comment: Hi, Johan: I have indexes defined on current_fsa_ip_id, ip_dim_id, member_ip_dim_id and base_ip_dim_id.

Comment: Hi, Chad: I am not supposed to use procedure or cursors. Is there any other way?

Comment: Learn to correctly use joins, this is a mess that is almost impossible to figure out. Implicit joins are a  SQL antipattern andtherer isnot excuse for every using them.

Comment: What database backend are you using, performance tuning is generally database sepecific.

Answer (score 0):

I'll have to spend more time dissecting your query, but it looks like you have unused tables in the subqueries.  The query optimizer should be omitting them, but if it's not then you get a cross join and massive row count inflation.

Update:  There are so many missing join conditions I can't even tell what you're trying to achieve with this query.  Where is the relation between "ip_dim member" and any of the other tables?  How do "ip_team_hierarchy_brdg" and "ip_dim base" relate to "fsa_ip_mth_end_fin_aggregate agg" and "fsa_ip_mth_end_fin_aggregate base1"?  What is the purpose of the self join on fsa_ip_mth_end_fin_aggregate?  If there's a hierarchical relation between records, you shouldn't be joining on the same field on both sides.

Update 2:  Now that you've given us the whole query, at least there don't appear to be any cross joins.  Apart from the advice others have offered about making sure you have appropriate indexes, I'm suspicious of the repeated subquery.  You were on the right track with your second attempt.  The subquery can be moved into the table references of the `UPDATE`, but you need to keep the table being updated separate from the aggregation.  I restructured your query to use ANSI JOINs to make it easier to troubleshoot, and moved the subquery:

```
update fsa_ip_mth_end_fin_aggregate tbl2
join (select agg.current_fsa_ip_id current_fsa_ip_id, 
             sum(base1.sr_gss_sls_cry_am) sr_gss_sls_cry_am, 
             sum(base1.acip_gss_sls_cry_am) acip_gss_sls_cry_am  
        from ip_dim base
        join ip_team_hierarchy_brdg on ip_team_hierarchy_brdg.base_ip_dim_id = base.ip_dim_id 
        join ip_dim member on ip_team_hierarchy_brdg.member_ip_dim_id = member.ip_dim_id 
        join fsa_ip_mth_end_fin_aggregate base1 on base1.current_fsa_ip_id = base.current_fsa_ip_id 
        join fsa_ip_mth_end_fin_aggregate agg on agg.current_fsa_ip_id = member.current_fsa_ip_id 
            and agg.current_fsa_ip_id = base1.current_fsa_ip_id
        where ip_team_hierarchy_brdg.active_in = 'Y' 
        and base.dim_active_in = 'Y'
        and member.dim_active_in = 'Y' 
        and ip_team_hierarchy_brdg.allocation_factor != 0 
        group by agg.current_fsa_ip_id
   ) tbl1
   on tbl1.current_fsa_ip_id = tbl2.current_fsa_ip_id
set tbl2.team_acip_gss_sls_cry_am = tbl1.acip_gss_sls_cry_am,
    tbl2.team_sr_gss_sls_cry_am = tbl1.sr_gss_sls_cry_am
```

This is MySQL syntax, I just realized you didn't specify your DBMS.  SQL Server has slightly different syntax for multi-table `UPDATE`, I'm not sure about others.

If I'm wrong and the repeated subquery isn't the culprit, this query structure should at least make it easier to optimize the aggregation subquery.

Comment: Hi, I have removed some of the where conditions from my query, as it is very lengthy... There are relations between all the tables. Please take a look at the entire query: